# Cleaning up orphaned metadata in information_schema

Tags: mysql, foreign-key, constraint, metadata, troubleshooting

OK - so the server (Percona 5.6 in this case) 'went away' in the middle of declaring a constraint like so:

```
alter table mytable
add constraint fk_mytable_myothertable
foreign key (myothertable_id)
references myothertable(id)
on delete restrict
on update restrict;
```

Now, the constraint does not show in

```
show create table mytable;
```

nor in

```
show keys from mytable;
```

yet when I try to re-run the creation of the constraint, I get

```
ERROR 1022 (23000): Can't write; duplicate key in table '#sql-115b_290'
```

--so, I searched through information_schema and found this:

```
mysql> select * from INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN where id like '%fk_mytable_myothertable%';
+------------------------------+------------------+------------------+--------+------+
| ID                           | FOR_NAME         | REF_NAME         | N_COLS | TYPE |
+------------------------------+------------------+------------------+--------+------+
| mydb/fk_mytable_myothertable | mydb/#sql-8a0_e6 | mydb/myothertable|      1 |    0 |
+------------------------------+------------------+------------------+--------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS where id like '%fk_mytable_myothertable%';
+------------------------------+-----------------+--------------+-----+
| ID                           | FOR_COL_NAME    | REF_COL_NAME | POS |
+------------------------------+-----------------+--------------+-----+
| mydb/fk_mytable_myothertable | myothertable_id | id           |   0 |
+------------------------------+-----------------+--------------+-----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

question is: can I just delete these orphaned references to the non-existent constraint, or is there more to cleaning up?

Comment: Meanwhile, file a bug report with http://bugs.mysql.com -- `ALTER` should be cleaner than that.

Comment: @rick-james - does it make sense to do that when I'm having the problem with a Percona server?

There's a deeper issue in that the server is crashing & restarting itself mid-process, but leaves no hint of what's wrong in the error log.

I also found that I can 'see' the temporary table: show create table `#sql-8a0_e6` actually shows the structure, but drop table returns 
    ERROR 1051 (42S02): Unknown table 'serpsalpha.#sql-8a0_e6'

Comment: `#sql*` files are temps left behind by the crash.  Did you run out of disk space?  Manually go into the filesystem and delete the file.  You could file a bug with Percona.  Percona gets the bugs reports/fixes from Oracle (who owns the link I gave you).

Comment: Thanks for the link & the explanation, @rick-james - I'll go ahead & file the bug. The total disk space used by the table I'm altering is ~60G and I have 800G free on the server where I'm doing it, so I don't think disk space is an issue. For now I'll get it done with mysqldump, sed, and rename table.

Comment: If tmpdir is a different 'filesystem', there could still be a disk space problem.

Comment: This is on Linodes - VMs with (in the example case) 1.2T /dev/xvda mapped to /, and 24G to devtmpfs - /tmp is just under /dev/xvda

Comment: That `ALTER` may need to make a copy of the table.  If it does it will put it in `tmpdir`.  If `tmpdir` is `/tmp`, then you rand out of disk space.  Do `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'tmpdir';`.

Comment: tmpdir=/tmp ; I think /tmp being directly under root in the /dev/xvda device means it would share the same 1.1T disk with 800G free.

Comment: An _intra_-filesystem `mv` requires only fiddling with the directory entries.  An _inter_-filesystem `mv` involves freeing up the space on the source fs and copying the data to the target fs.  This is a `cp`.  Sure, they may be on the same _physical_ drive, but the OS cannot take advantage of that.

Comment: In `C` renaming a file (`mv` in *nix) is two steps: `link()` and `unlink()`.  `link` does a "hard link", which is restricted to the same filesystem.  `unlink` decrements the reference count and (in this case) won't actually delete the file from the filesystem.

Comment: I don't understand your point, Rick: with 800G free in /dev/xvda, cp-ing the alter table mechanism creating duplicates as temp tables would have no issue, given the available space is 800G and the table is only 50G. /tmp is just a subdirectory off the root of /dev/xvda means /tmp has 800G available to it - how does the difference between mv & cp relate?

Comment: I'm sorry.  I misread you.  If `/tmp` is in the _same_ filesystem with mysql's directory, then my last few comments are irrelevant.  (And I am stumped about your problem.)

Comment: No worries. Thanks for taking the time to look into it all the same. It sure looks like a memory problem because it leaves no trace in the error log, but so far I haven't a clue where the problem is. If I do find out, I'll update this thread.

Answer (score 1):

The way that I found to "solve" this problem is fairly annoying, but there is a script that handles it.

Essentially, you need the `ibdata1` and `ib_logfile*` files to go away (they contain the mappings of foreign keys, among other things). The only *safe* way to do this is to export all of your databases, stop mysql, remove the files, start mysql, and then import the files.

The script that helps solve this problem is https://github.com/uberhacker/shrink-ibdata1, even though the stated purpose of this script is different, it *does* solve the problem.